# Can you edit existing attributes in QField?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qfield

Can you edit existing attributes in QField?  I've researched and tried various options in QGIS/QField but no luck.

Comment: yes using 'digitise mode' simple form, example video 'Editing Saved Features' https://livelihoods-and-landscapes.com/qgis_qfield_tutorials/lesson_2.html#QField (depends on the formats you are using)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I looked at the link you sent and I see in that version there is a way to edit existing attributes by clicking on an icon (pg 6, bottom image, icon in upper right corner, "A" with pencil).  That icon/option is NOT available on my version of the QField app 1.10 Android.  Any other ideas?  Thanks again!!

Comment: There is no doubt you can edit. You must have something wrong in your set-up.
Provide detail with screenshots of the project set-up in QGIS. Is the layer file based or a database connection. Is it configured to be editable in Project Properties_Qfield. Are you using QField on Android or iOS. Where is the project stored on your phone / tablet - in the QField directory, root directory, somehwre else?